# UInt32 to IntPtr

Tags: c#

I have the following problem:

```
public class ListenThread : SocketInvoke
{
            [DllImport("Ws2_32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public unsafe static extern UInt32 WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(UInt32 cEvents, IntPtr hEventObject,
            UInt32 fWaitAll, UInt32 dwTimeout, Boolean fAlertable);

            public void ListenConnections(NetSharedData data)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    unsafe
                    {
                        if (WSAWaitForMultipleEvents((UInt32)1, data.signal, (UInt32)0, (UInt32)100, false) != WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
                        {
                        }
                   }
             }
}
```

data.signal is a UInt32 how i can cast it to IntPtr?, i try:

```
IntPtr signal = (IntPtr)data.signal;
```

but it doesn't work because i need a pointer to data.signal (UInt32) type and not the int value as an pointer, that will make a memory exception.

An C++ example of what i need:

```
int signal = 0;
int* psignal = &signal;
```

Comment: well, the code you've provided does not contain `IntPtr signal = data.signal;`

Comment: And **always** tell us what you mean by "it doesn't work"

Comment: i said i try that, because i don't know how to convert UInt32 to IntPtr. The code provides the API where i need to set an IntPtr type and data.signal is UInt32.

Comment: does it tell you `Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'System.IntPtr'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`?.  For future reference, It's helpful to post the error message, like that, instead of saying "it doesn't work"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new IntPtr(data.signal);
```

You are going to have problems on a 64-bit platform because data.signal is only hanging on to the lower 32-bits of an address. If NetSharedData is yours you should consider changing the type of signal to IntPtr.

If you are trying to get an address to data.signal:

```
new IntPtr(&data.signal);
```

I'm not sure this would properly pin the object (to prevent the memory manager from relocating it), I would do the following:

1) Change the PInvoke signature:

```
public unsafe static extern UInt32 WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(UInt32 cEvents, 
       void* hEventObject, UInt32 fWaitAll, UInt32 dwTimeout, Boolean fAlertable);
```

2) use fixed to pin the object

```
fixed (void* s = &data.signal)
{
    if (WSAWaitForMultipleEvents((UInt32)1, s, (UInt32)0, (UInt32)100, false) != WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to use fixed on data.signal but it tells me that it cant resolve the address of the object.

Comment: If signal is a property then you'll need to make a local copy of it's value.

Answer (score 2):

This also compiles

```
        UInt32 unsignedInt = 6;
        IntPtr iptr = new IntPtr(unsignedInt);
```

so maybe this is what you want

```
IntPtr signal = new IntPtr(data.signal);
```

Comment: IntPtr should be pointer to int and that casting is just assigning the int value as a pointer which will make an exception.

What i need is a pointer to an int value (IntPtr) that contains that unsignedint = 6

Comment: It compiles or it runs and doesn't error? You can cast anything, but whether or not it blows up is a different story.